# Notepad++ find any repeated dates

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find and mark in Notepad++ any repeated dates from a txt file:

```
2016-05-24
2016-05-25
2016-05-26 <--- mark this
2016-05-26 <--- mark this
2016-05-26 <--- mark this
2016-05-27
2016-05-28
```

I have tried with this to find dates `([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)` and it works to simply find the dates but I don't know which regex should I use for find *any* *repeated* date.

Comment: depending on your input (show real input), how about something like [`(^.+)(?:\R\1$)+`](https://regex101.com/r/JJbSq4/1)

Comment: It's not possible to do this, regex is not used to do something like this

Comment: @ChuckLu: Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select "Mark" tab
- Find what: `(^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$)(?:\R\1$)+`
- **CHECK** *Bookmark line*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(                   # group 1
  ^                   # beginning of line
    \d{4}-\d\d-\d\d     # date
  $                   # end of line
)                   # end group
(?:                 # non capture group
    \R                  # any kind of linebreak
    \1                  # backreference to group 1
  $                   # end of line
)+                  # end of group, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]